# NavigateUrl with aspxerrorpath error

Tags: asp.net

I have this code in my Aspx page:

```
<asp:hyperlink Text="Staff Directory" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/directory.aspx" ID="Directory" />
```

When I check the HTML source code, I see this:

```
<li><a href="/directory/">Faculty &amp; Staff Directory</a></li>
```

So, it is ignoring the root path when it is rendering the code to HTML. I tried many solutions from the internet but none worked. Any advice?

Here the error after disabling custom error:
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<customErrors mode="Off">

<a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/directory.aspx") %>">
```

This also assumes that directory.aspx resides in the root path.

Comment: It did not work. I got this: error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/directory.aspx

Comment: disable custom erros in your web.config file!

Comment: You have the custom errors entry in the web.config to Off.
Look at the answer, otherwise a custom error page with no error details will be displayed.

Comment: Yes, I did and that is what show up when clicked on the link.

Comment: This is still a custom error page, are you sure about using the right web.config file?

Comment: I have: Web.config and web.debug.config files. I turned customerror to off in web.config only.

Comment: Difficult to say without further information. Do you use any additonal error handling code? You are doing something wrong...
But if you look at the markup of the link, how does it look like when using the solution I posted as an answer?

Comment: It is still the same:<td><a href="/directory.aspx">t</a></td>

Comment: To be honest, this is not my project. I am trying to find my way through and fix a bunch of broken links with similar problem. I have 5 other pages with similar path but none can find the right root path to connect to.

Comment: Didn't you say, it rendered like this in your question:
<a href="/directory/"> ?

Now it looks good, but you have an error in the application somewhere, but that'sa different question..

Comment: yes, I see this <a href="/directory/">  when I look at the source code for the page. The corresponding page is in the root with the main page of the website. So, I am not really following your point.

Comment: OK, now I understand that nothing wrong with the link. The error must be something else.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I figured it out. The previous person, who created the project, has made a folder for directory, and did not delete the old directory page. I change the link to the new folder and everything is working perfectly.